# Classical bottom-up iterative approach for 0-1 Knapsack variation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am not good at DP and trying to improve with practice over time. I was trying to solve [this](https://onlinejudge.org/external/108/10819.pdf) problem.

> Given prices and favor-value of n items, determine the max value that
> you can buy for a pocket money of m. The twist here is that once you
> spend above $2000, you can get refund of $200, so effectively your
> purchasing power becomes m+200.

I could solve this using recursive approach, but I am more curious to solve it with classical iterative 0-1 Knapsack bottom-up approach as given below, by some modification :

```
int Knapsack(vector<int> wt, vector<int> val, int cap)
{
       int i,j;
       int n = wt.size();
       for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
               t[i][0] = 0;
       for(j=0;j<=cap;j++)  //cap is the max allowed weight of knapsack
               t[0][j] = 0;

       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
               for(j=1;j<=cap;j++)
               {
   
                       if(wt[i-1]<=j)
                               t[i][j] = max(val[i-1]+t[i-1][j-wt[]i-1], t[i-1][j]);
                       else
                               t[i][j] = t[i-1][j];
               }
       }
       return t[n][cap];
}
```

In the above, the `wt[]` can actually become the price of each item and favor-value is `val[]`. The `cap` needs to be modified to `cap+200` but with some tricky checks which I couldn't figure out after trying for 2 days now. What modifications can I do here to take extra $200 for shopping above $2000. I tried many approaches but failed. I tried searching on internet but mostly there are recursive approaches used which I have already figured out or they have use space saving trick by using 1-D array. But I want to modify the classical solution to solve it, so as to improve and verify my understanding. Can some please give me a hint or direction.

Comment: If you can share your recursive code then it will be fairly easy to convert it into top-down approach.

Comment: @tom : You can refer this code here : https://saicheems.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/uva-10819-trouble-of-13-dots/. Its similar to what I could come with. Its already top-down, I would want to develop a new bottom-up solution using 2D-array with as min modifications as possible to the classical code above in question.

Comment: not elegant but should work: make the maximum weight `m + 200` at the beginning of your code, run the knapsack, then run a separate loop where `if (x + 200 >= 2000) t[n][x] = max(t[n][x], t[n][x + 200])`, then return `max(t[n][0...cap])`

Comment: Not sure if I got your solution correctly, but this does not work for the input : p (max weight)=1900 and items as (2000,5) (1950,2) (101,1). The correct answer is 3 but I get 5 with this approach.